# android layout design by percentage

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am testing my app on multiple devices: LG, Galaxy S5, HTC One, Nexus 5. My layout files are defined in xml. I am finding that my layouts are not device independent. What I mean is that `10dp` means different things on different devices. I do not wish to create custom `ViewGroup`s in java by extending the typical `ViewGroup`s. I would rather all my ViewGroups be the typical ones. What I mean is, in a CustomViewGroup, I can get the size of the device, and then from there calculate pixels and then layout my child views from there. But that's a lot of work, and frankly xml layouts have to be good enough to handle multiple devices. So I rather think that the problem is my skills as opposed to the limitations of xml layout files.

My layouts are not so fancy that I should be experiencing this problem, so I am wondering what is the general guidance for creating xml layout that will work on these different device sizes. I am not talking about tablets, just phones of different sizes.

Using LinearLayout with weights help, but weights do not account for margins. So even when I wrap all my RelativeLayouts and other such ViewGroups in LinearLayouts by using include as in

```
<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.10"
    layout="@layout/custome_status_bar" />
```

I still run into problems. So are there general guidance for creating xml layouts that work across devices? No the developer sites have not been a source of help.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the problem you are facing with the margins and layout_weight?

Comment: @Distwo the app is not out yet, so I am very limited in that regard. Which is why I was hoping for some general guidance similar to `use LinearLayout with weights`. So since dp is not exactly percentage, what would be, for instance?

Comment: I would recommend you to read the documentation in http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html (look at Alternative drawables specifically). This page would give an understanding of variation in layouts.